# Kubernetes with an UDP loadbalancer with sticky sessions based on IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, udp, load-balancing

I'm trying to deploy an UDP-based application on kubernetes, but I'm having troubles finding a suitable cloud provider that has an UDP loadbalancer with IP-based sticky sessions.

I have tried using DigitalOcean Kubernetes Service (DOKS) but they don't support UDP loadbalancers.

EKS (AWS' kubernetes service) provides UDP support with NLB for example, but they don't seem to have sticky sessions on that type of loadbalancer, only on the classic LB.

Is there another cloud provider (I'm thinking of GCE or Azure) that provides my required functionalities out of the box?

I'm asking this here to know if anyone else has had the same problem and maybe has already tried various solutions, and has already found the perfect fit.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions

Comment: thank you @jordanm , i was looking for a specific annotation to add to my yaml definition and didn't think of using the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jordanm posted, the answer was to apply the stickiness parameter through the ec2 console.

Answer (score 2):

I know in Nginx Ingress Controller (which I know [works with AWS and NLB](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws) with UDP support as you stated) can [expose UDP services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) and [supports sticky sessions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/). I have not done this in AWS or any other cloud provider, but I have with similar use cases on bare-metal.